# Why does every Laurent Series have a singular point on the outer and inner boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, analyticity, analytic-functions

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) says : "On the boundary of the annulus, one cannot make a general statement, except to say that there is at least one point on the inner boundary and one point on the outer boundary such that $f(z)$ cannot be holomorphically continued to those points"

Why is this true? I thought that if not, then $f(z)$ is analytic on a neighbourhood of the boundary (not sure if this holds) and thus the outer (or inner) radius is bigger than our original one.

Is this correct? I can't justify why $f(z)$ must be analytic on a neighbourhood of the boundary.

Comment: Use a compactness argument.

Comment: Inner and outer boundary ??? For a function $f$ analytic on $U = \{|z| < r\}$ what makes sense is to add to $U$ all the points $a$ of $|z|=r$ where $f$ is analytic, from the Taylor series at $a$ add to $U$ a small disk around $a$, the obtained domain is simply connected and the question is if it contains $|z|=r$ or if it misses at least one point of $|z|=r$ (by the Cauchy integral formula the latter happens iff the radius of convergence of the Taylor series at $z=0$ is $r$). It works the same way for Laurent series and annulus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The result for power series is analogous:

Say $D(0,R)$ is the domain of convergence of some power series. Suppose for everyy $z$ with  $|z|=R$ there exists $r(z)>0$ such that $f$  extends to $D(z,r(z))$. Compactness of the boundary shows there exists $R'>R$ such that $$D(0,R')\subset D(0,R)\cup\bigcup_{|z|=R}D(z,r(z)).$$So $f$ is holomorphic in a larger disk.

**Edit:** It appears that it's not clear why $R'>R$ as above exists.

> > **Lemma.** Suppose $K\subset V\subset \Bbb C$, $K$ is compact and $V$ is open. There exists $\delta>0$ such that $D(z,\delta)\subset V$ for  every $z\in K$.

**Why the lemma gives $R'$ as above:** Let $K=\overline{D(0,r)}$, $V=D(0,R)\cup\bigcup_{|z|=R} D(z,r(z))$. If $\delta>0$ is as in the lemma then $R'=R+\delta$ works.

**Proof of the lemma:** Suppose not. Then there exists a sequence $(z_n)\subset K$ and a sequence $(w_n)\subset\Bbb C\setminus V$ such that $|w_n-z_n|\to0$. **Details:** For each $n$ there exists $x_n\in K$ such that $D(x_m,1/n)\not\subset V$. Let $w_n\in D(x_n,1/n)\setminus V$. Then $w_n\notin V$ ad $|x_n-w_n|<1/n$.

Since $K$ is compact there is a subsequence $z_{n_j}\to p\in K$. Hence $w_{n_j}\to p$. Choose $\rho>0$ so $D(p,\rho)\subset V$; now we have $|p-w_{n_j}|<\rho$ for large $j$, hence $w_{n_j}\in V$ for large $j$, contradiction.

Comment: Why does such an R' exist?

Comment: @Saad Since the boundary $\{|z|=R\}$ is compact it is covered by finitely  many of the disks $D(z,r(z)$...

Comment: Then there exists one with minimum $r$ > 0 and our function is analytic in $D(0, R + r)$? I can't visualize why this must be true ( the analytic part )

Comment: @Saad No, that doesn't quite give $D(0,R+t)$.

Comment: @Saad I added a more detailed proof...

Comment: Why must such sequences exist? All we know is that there exists a $z \in K$ such that for all $r > 0$, $D(z, r)$ is not contained in $V$.

Comment: @Saad I don't understand your question at all. (i) Why must _what__ sequences exist? (ii) You say "All we know is..." first, how do we know that? Second, if we do know that we're done, because it contradicts  the fact that $K\subset V$ annd $V$ is open.

Comment: @Saad Oh, I see what happened. What we do know from our "Suppose not" is that for every $r>0$ there exists $z\in K$ such that $D(z,r)\not\subset V$. That does **not** say there exists $z\in K$ such that for all $r>0$ etc!

Comment: @Saad I added yet more details...

Comment: Thanks! Lastly, why does $R'$ work? Is it because all the points at distance $<R$ are in $D(0, R)$ and the ones with distance $>=R$ are in the disks of radius delta centered at the points of the boundary of the original disk?

Comment: @Saad Yes. Stating what you said more carefully, if $R\le|w|<R'$ then there exists $z$ with $|z|=R$ and $|z-w|<\delta$.

Comment: And such a $z$ exists because one can draw a straight line from 0 to $w$ and it will intersect the circle of radius $R$ at some point, which is $z$?

Comment: @Saad Right. Equivalently, let $z=Rw/|w|$.

Answer (score 2):

It can be proved that if the domain of an analytic function $f$ contains an annulus$$\{z\in\mathbb C\mid r<\lvert z-z_0\rvert<R\},$$then there is one and only one Laurent series centered at $z_0$ which converges to $f(z)$ at each point of the annulus. Now, suppose that for each $w\in\mathbb C$ such that $\lvert w-z_0\rvert=r$ you can extend $f$ analytically to a disk centered at $w$. Then, since$$\{w\in\mathbb C\mid\lvert w-z_0\rvert=r\}\tag1$$is compact, you can pick finitely many such disks that cover the set $(1)$. So, $f$ can be extended to a larger annulus$$\{z\in\mathbb C\mid r'<\lvert z-z_0\rvert<R\},$$with $r'<r$. But then, by the theorem that I mentioned above, the Laurent series must converge on that larger annulus too.

Comment: A couple of questions:

1) Why can we extend $f$ analytically to a disk centered at $w$?

2) Why can we cover $(1)$ with finitely many such disks? My definition of compact is closed and bounded (or sequentially compact).

3) Why can we extend $f$ to a larger annulus?

Comment: 1) I proved that if we can extend $f$ to a disk centerd at each $w$ such that $\lvert w-z_0\rvert=r$, then the Laurent series cannot converge only on the original annulus. 2) I used here the definition of compact: a set is compact if every open cover has a finite sub-cover. And all those disks *are* an open cover. 3) Because otherwise there would be a sequence of points from the union of the boundaries of those disks converging to a $w'$ such that $\lvert w'-z_0\rvert=r$, which is impossible, since the union of those disks is an open set containing the circle with center $z_0$ and radius $r$.

Comment: I still do not understand why there exists an $r'$ smaller than $r$ on which $f$ convereges

Comment: A full answer is too long for a comment. I suggest that you ask this as another question.